# If empty doesn't work in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to display something if avatar record in my db doesn't exist. I am using empty() function but it's not working. it's displaying img and alt="avatar" even if avatar is null. Can anyone help?

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
          <td class="user-table-information">

              @if(!empty($user->user_data->where('user_id', $user->id)->avatar))
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>      
              @else

              @foreach($user->user_data as $data)
                <img src="{{ asset('/storage/uploads/avatars/'. $data->avatar) }}" class="avatar" alt="avatar">  
              @endforeach
                @endif
                 </td>
```

Comment: How are you getting your `$users` data. The fact that you need to do `->where('user_id',$user->id)` indicates something is wrong

Comment: `$user->user_data->where('user_id', $user->id)` You probably need to add `->first()` before `->avatar` for `empty` to work properly.

Comment: Soooo maybe I'm missing something but don't you mean to use `empty()` instead of `! empty()`? As in, show the placeholder if the avatar *is* empty? Looks like your logic is backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use isEmpty() instead. See example below:

```
@if( !$someDBcollection->isEmpty() )
echo "its not empty";
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This just feels like you have not done enough (query wise) before sending to blade... is user_data a collection (looks like it is), and if so it looks like you have a collection on a user that holds all users avatars!

Think you just need to do your limiting on an earlier query.. Im going to presume some things, but...

In your controller:

$users = User::with('user_data')->all();

or better yet, if it is just the avatar path you need, and they need to be separate models, just use a relationship...

```
$users = User::with('avatar')->all();

class Avatar()
{
    ...  some stuff here

    public function relativePath()
    {
        return "/storage/uploads/avatars/" . $this.filename;
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User')
    }

}
```

public class User()
{
    ... some stuff

```
public function avatar()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Avatar');
}
```

}

Then simply use it as:

```
<img src="{{ $user->avatar->relativePath() }}"/>
```

Like I said, its an abstract answer, but with little information to go on, hopefully I have been able to give an answer of sorts :)